# Future / Completer behavior in dart not running asynchronously

Tags: dart, future

I am just trying to understand the behavior of Futures.  Here is a sample code:

```
import'dart:async';

main() {

  Future short = shortWait();
  Future medium = mediumWait();
  Future long = longWait();
  long.then((String e)=>print(e));
  medium.then((String e)=> print(e));
  short.then((String e)=> print(e));
  }

  Future<String> longWait() {
  Completer c = new Completer<String>();
  for (int i=0; i<100000000; i++);   // creating long latency
  c.complete("long");
  return c.future;
  }
  Future<String> mediumWait() {
    Completer c = new Completer<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<10000; i++);    // creating medium length latency
    c.complete("medium");
    return c.future;
  }
  Future<String> shortWait() {
    Completer c = new Completer<String>();
    c.complete("short");    // no latency
    return c.future;
  }


// short  
// medium
// long
```

I have noticed a few things.  First, the code seems to be synchronous, and the longest latency function, longWait(), is blocking.  The output doesn't display until everything is available, and then displays all at once.  I would think it should display whatever is available first, and then display as the Futures become complete.

Second, the display order seems to reflect the order in which the Future short/medium/long = shortWait/mediumWait/longWait() is displayed.  i.e. change the order of those lines, and the order of the output is changed accordingly.  It does not matter how long the latency is for each method, nor does it make any difference in the order of display for short/medium/long.then((e) => print(e)).

I want the code to 1) display output when the data is available, and 2) the order of output should reflect the latency of the function.  I am not actually trying to do anything other than understand the underlying concept of Futures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that *asynchronous* in Dart does not mean *in parallel*.

What you are essentially doing in your example is putting five tasks on a queue:

1. Count to 100000000
2. Print 'long'
3. Count to 10000
4. Print 'medium'
5. Print 'short'

So they get executed in that order.

In Dart, *asynchronous* means that code does not have to be *blocked* when waiting for something to happen. That something is commonly a function provided by a core library such as getting data from a file, or an interaction over the network - tasks that get executed by the operating system or the browser.

One way to think of this is that a Dart program can execute 'in parallel' with stuff being done by the operating system or browser, but not itself.

Dart can also execute code 'in parallel' with waiting for a timer to fire. E.g.:

```
import 'dart:async';

main() {

   // Long latency
  (new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 5)).then((_) => print('long')));

  // Medium latency
  (new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 2)).then((_) => print('medium')));

  // Short latency
  (new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) => print('short')));

  print('go');
}
```

Prints:

```
go
short
medium
long
```

Comment: Just adding that for doing things in parallel in Dart, there are [Isolates](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.21.0/dart-isolate/dart-isolate-library.html) with convenient [IsolateChannel](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/stream_channel/1.5.0/stream_channel/IsolateChannel-class.html) for bidirectional communication.

Comment: Thanks.  That helps a lot.  The latency I added is just representative of some really complicated calculation.  The time delay is not really the same thing, as I am sure you would agree.  With that in mind, are you saying that there is no easy way to make these functions work in parallel, without using Isolates, and only using Futures?

Comment: @rchkm You can set a delay of 0 seconds and do the complicated calculation in there.

Comment: @rchkm Yes concurrent/parallel functions only using Isolates. Dart is single threaded which is good thing IMO. Reasons are 1) parallel programming with shared memory ala Java was proven to be error prone 2) transpilling to JS, which is single threaded as well. Some further useful links: https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures, https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/performance/event-loop

Comment: @rchkm Correct the only way of doing parallel processing in Dart is with an Isolate.

Answer (score 2):

```
Future<String> longWait() {
  Completer c = new Completer<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++); // creating long latency
  c.complete("long");
  return c.future;
}
```

This isn't doing things asynchronously. You're returning the future only after the for loop has completed. This makes this function synchronous.

To make it asynchronous, try the following:

```
Future<String> longWait() {
  Completer c = new Completer<String>();

  new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 4), () {
    c.complete('long');
  });

  return c.future;
}

Future<String> mediumWait() {
  Completer c = new Completer<String>();

  new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    c.complete('medium');
  });

  return c.future;
}

Future<String> shortWait() {
  Completer c = new Completer<String>();

  new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 0), () {
    c.complete('short');
  });

  return c.future;
}
```

Ideally, you can avoid using `Completer` altogether because `Future.delayed` returns a future.

```
Future<String> longWait() {
  return new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 10), ()=>'long');
}
Future<String> mediumWait() {
  return new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 5), ()=>'medium');
}
Future<String> shortWait() {
  return new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 0), ()=>'short');
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The entire code still pauses, waits for everything, and then runs when complete.  The order of printing still seems tied to the order in which I create the Future objects in main().  If the Future only returns after the loops, shouldn't the shortWait() function return a value first, and followed by mediumWait(), and then longWait()?  When I use new Future.delayed(new Duration(seconds: 10)), I don't think the system is actually waiting 10 seconds.  Thanks again.  I put this on the Dartpad.  (https://dartpad.dartlang.org/3f22a756c9f4c98d55f8dbb2eb062314)

Comment: When you're using a time delay, it returns a Future so you don't have to use a Completer. See this https://dartpad.dartlang.org/e373c3f73e7b8d2e5f11a8b0ee290195

Comment: @rchkm The code I had written in the answer earlier was wrong. I have updated the answer with the correct code.